# How to deep clone iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is there any way to deep clone iframe?

Basic jQuery cloning just makes another iframe with the same src. What I want to achieve is a way to clone the iframe and it's exact current content (ie. any possible input values, any DOM modifications through javascript etc.).

```
var clone = iframe.contents().find('html').clone();
```

When i clone the HTML attribute and all its children's, modifications etc I have these problems:

1. I'm missing the DOCTYPE
2. how do I insert it into the new iFrame?

Comment: Missing the DOCTYPE shouldn't matter, AFAIK: it's a signal to the parser. Since you already have DOM elements, they shouldn't need to be parsed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you clone the `iframe` creating another `iframe` then you *deep* clone your `iframe`! It's source is somewhere else and it'll be downloaded when you assign its `src` attribute.

### Test

Imagine you have as source a (**non cached**) page that prints the current time. Put an `iframe` on your page, wait 10 seconds then clone it. The new `iframe` will download its content and the 2nd `iframe` will have a different content (the time).

### "Real" deep cloning

**EDIT**: if you need a deep raw clone you may get the innerHTML and inject it inside the iframe. Solution from [Michael Mahemof](http://softwareas.com):

```
// Creates the new iframe, add the iframe where you want
var newframe = document.createElement("iframe");
document.body.appendChild(newframe); 

// We need the iframe document object, different browsers different ways
var frameDocument = newFrame.document;
if (newFrame.contentDocument)
 frameDocument = newFrame.contentDocument;
else if (newFrame.contentWindow)
 frameDocument = newFrame.contentWindow.document;

// We open the document of the empty frame and we write desired content.
// originalHtmlContent is a string where you have the source iframe HTML content.
frameDocument.open();
frameDocument.writeln(originalHtmlContent);
frameDocument.close();
```

Comment: What I want is to deep clone the iFrame with its contents, not just set the same src. In your case, I'd like to have another iframe which has the _same_ time as the original.

Comment: Added "real deep cloning" section

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it won't clone dynamic elements, such as values of input fields.

Comment: No, it does. If you get your iframe content with innerHTML you'll get all your inputs and their values.

Comment: No you don't. Of course, if you set it on HTML code itself, _then_ you get it, but if I just type something on a input field and clone the iFrame through innerHTML, the value doesn't get transferred over. However, I was able to use the cloning for this: InnerHTML for the main HTML and cloning for body. TY! :)

Comment: This one really helped me out today - thanks.  Using open/write/close was the key I was missing.  just using `innerHTML` was <b>not</b> working.