# Sync position of two content_editable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, caret

I have two content_editable `<body>` elements, that have the same exact content.  I need to make one reflect the position of the other.  So, if the user moves the caret down and scrolls the content, I need to make that change happen on the other element.

I tried using jQuery's scrollTop, to no avail.  I've also looked at a few caret based positioning solutions, but nothing has worked yet.

A bit more background.  I have a magnifier widget, that uses the css3 zoom feature to magnify content.  This is done by duplicating the content via HTML and then zooming in a div on that content.

There are ckeditors in the content, which means there are iframe's with content_editable `<body>` tags.

When the content is duplicated, it does not preserve the position of the body's scroll.  How can I get the position copied into my copied content?

PS. The only essential browser is Chrome.

Comment: something LIKE ifr1.window.onscroll=function(){ifr2.window.documentElement.scrollTop=this.documentElement.scrollTop}

Comment: I've got it almost working.  I get the scrollTop off the original `<html>` element, and then I apply it to the copy, but the copy doesn't move, its scrolltop remains 0.

Comment: some browsers/doctypes use document.body instead of document.documentElement. or, if you have a scrollable container, you need to read, dupe, and write that pos instead. get the right scroll values dumping to the console, then wire into the 2nd iframe.

Comment: Found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702406/how-to-deep-clone-iframe.  I needed to get a more faithful copy of the document.